# How to persist a graph with unrelated tables

Tags: acumatica

Lets say I have a graph as follows

```
    public PXCancel<DAC1> Cancel;
    public PXSave<DAC1>   Save;

    public PXSelect<DAC1> View;
    public PXSelect<DAC2> Entities;
    public PXSelect<DAC3> Mappings;
```

Currently, when a change is made to the data view of DAC2, when the save button is pressed, nothing is persisted (even though the save button becomes enabled on the UI once the change is made). Once I make a change to DAC1, then the changes to both DAC1 and DAC2 are persisted successfully.

How can I make it so that when only a change to DAC2 is made, the save button works?

Comment: Technically you can add logic to mark the Cache of the DAC1 as updated when DAC2 or DAC3 are updated.

Comment: Thanks, if you add that as an answer ill OK it

Answer (score 0):

You can try marking the record of the DAC1 as updated in the cache when the record of the DAC2 or DAC3 is updated.

```
graph.Caches[typeof(DAC1)].MarkUpdated(record);
```